# Getting previous month data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a transaction records table in ms-access with item field, date field and quantity field. I would like to add a new column, with transaction quantity for the previous month. 
For example, I have a row that looks like this:

```
+----------------------------+
| Item A | 1/11/2018 | 8,000 |
+----------------------------+
| Item A | 1/12/2018 | 7,000 |
+----------------------------+
```

And I want to add in a new column that shows previous month's transaction quantity, which will look like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Item A | 1/11/2018 | 8,000 | -     |
+------------------------------------+
| Item A | 1/12/2018 | 7,000 | 8,000 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone suggest how do I query this in access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get previous month's data alongside current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986917/get-previous-months-data-alongside-current-month)

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you can do something like this. MS Access does not have [LAG function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql), as similar to T-SQL.

```
SELECT ItemA, Date, Quantity as currentQuantity, 
(SELECT top 1 Quantity FROM Table1 new WHERE new.Date = dateadd("m",-1,tbl.Date)) as previousQuantity
FROM Table1 tbl 
ORDER BY tbl.Date
```

Comment: It is one month, not one day.